# What is meaning and correct grammar of "looking to lock up" expression?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I have come across a sentence *"I was talking about the fourth quarter of game seven, when you're looking to lockup a championship..."*. I checked in all available dictionaries and did not find meaningful explanation. From a context I guessed it means to win a championship prematurely according to some tournament system, but there are still doubts. Also Google returned me a page that said *"Porsche Looking to Lock Up World Championship in Shanghai"* without verb *be* before *"Looking"*. So my questions are: did I guess the meaning correctly and what is correct grammar to use the expression (with/without be)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it right: "when you're looking" has the verb **to be** before looking. The headline "Porsche Looking to" leaves out the word **is**, and it means they are seeking to complete the championship by winning it solidly: The auto maker **is in pursuit of a quick finish** to the race

Definition of [Look](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/looking) 2.c. To turn one's expectations:

> looked to us for a solution.

Both your examples have the same meaning: aiming to (looking to) achieve or own (lock up).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is still not clear about omitting "be/is" in the second expression. Is it some sort of a gerund clause? Could you point me to a related grammar topic?

Comment: Headlines Short.  Words Stingy. Universal Truth: Less More. Your search found a sportscar magazine headline, and headlines break rules to save space and to entice readers to read further. No gerund is used, but the obvious words are left out to save space: Porsche (is actively in the process of) Looking to Win.